# Why are the variables in a VAR model considered endogenous?

Tags: vector-autoregression, endogeneity, exogeneity

Does it have to do with the interdependence of one equation on the lagged values of its own as well as the other equations?

If I remember correctly, in simultaneous equations, cross-causality is also a cause for endogeneity, but in VAR models the causality moves in one direction, the past impacts the future and not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a bivariate zero-mean VAR(1) model
\begin{aligned}
y_{1,t} &= a_{1,1} y_{1,t-1} a_{1,2} y_{2,t-1} + u_{1,t}, \\
y_{2,t} &= a_{2,1} y_{1,t-1} a_{2,2} y_{2,t-1} + u_{2,t} 
\end{aligned}
or in matrix notation, $\mathbb{y}_t=A \mathbb{y}_{t-1} + \mathbb{u}_t$.

Both $y_{1,t}$ and $y_{2,t}$ are dependent variables, each in its own equation, so they are explained by the model. Thus, they are **endogenous**. The lags, on the other hand, might seem to be exogenous, as they are not explained by the model... or are they?

The model applies for every $t$. E.g. for $t=6$,
\begin{aligned}
y_{1,6} &= a_{1,1} y_{1,5} a_{1,2} y_{2,5} + u_{1,6}, \\
y_{2,6} &= a_{2,1} y_{1,5} a_{2,2} y_{2,5} + u_{2,6} 
\end{aligned}
and for $t=5$,
\begin{aligned}
y_{1,5} &= a_{1,1} y_{1,4} a_{1,2} y_{2,4} + u_{1,5}, \\
y_{2,5} &= a_{2,1} y_{1,4} a_{2,2} y_{2,4} + u_{2,5}. 
\end{aligned}
Thus, if we decrease $t$ by 1, the seemingly exogenous variables $y_{1,5}$ and $y_{2,5}$ turn out to be endogenous, as the model explains them, too. Therefore, all the $y$ variables can be considered endogenous in this model.

(Also, for a specific time period such as $t=6$, $y_{1,5}$ and $y_{2,5}$ are **predetermined**. This is a useful feature for deriving some desirable properties of least squares or other estimators of the models parameters.)

You can now generalized from the bivariate zero-mean VAR(1) to a $k$-variate VAR($p$) model with nonzero mean, and the same logic goes through.